# ajax jquery fadein td class

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, fadein

I have a table td class named "**on**" that I would like to fade in when Ajax refreshes the table. 
For some reason it wont fade in.

Here is the code so far:

```
function Ajax()
{
var xmlHttp;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
document.getElementById('refreshtable').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('Ajax()',20000);
xmlHttp.open("GET","mypage.cfm",true);
xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
window.onload=function(){
setTimeout('Ajax()',20000);
$(".on").hide().html(html).fadeIn(); //jquery fadein
}

<table>
<div id="refreshtable">
<tr>
<td class="on">#data1#</td>
<td class="on">#data2#</td>
<td class="on">#data3#</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: And? What's happening/working/not working/going on/etc?

Comment: refreshes without fadein

Comment: Wrap the content in a Div. I believe I have had that same trouble with a TD. It can't "fade" in like you want. Unless it's data from a database, I would wrap it in a div anyway. More control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use jQuery's implementation of AJAX? It will shrink your code quite a bit.

```
$(function () {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        $.get('mypage.cfm', function (response) {
            $('.on').fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).html(response).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }, 20000);
});
```

Here is a demonstration of this functioning properly: http://apexeleven.com/stackoverflow/jquery.get/test.html